# where will the system search for dynamic libraries?

Tags: libraries

I want to know where the system will search for dynamic libraries. Let's take nxclient as an example. ldd /usr/NX/bin/nxclient gives me some output, for example

```
libpng12.so.0 => /usr/NX/lib/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007fcb4a16f000)
```

Now why did the system select /usr/NX/lib/libpng12.so.0 and not for example /usr/lib64/libpng12.so.0? Both exist. Where is this configured? /etc/ld.so.conf* does not contain /usr/NX and my $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible that the library path might be hard coded in the binary.

From the [RPATH Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath)

> The dynamic linker of the GNU C Library and its derivative Embedded
>   GLIBC implement a rather complicated algorithm for searching for
>   shared libraries. The basic search order is:
>
> 1. The (colon-separated) paths in the DT_RPATH dynamic section attribute of the binary if present and DT_RUNPATH attribute does not
>      exist.
> 2. The (colon-separated) paths in the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, unless the executable is a setuid/setgid binary, in
>      which case it is ignored. LD_LIBRARY_PATH can be overridden by calling
>      the dynamic linker with the option --library-path (e.g.
>      /lib/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path $HOME/mylibs myprogram).
> 3. The (colon-separated) paths in the DT_RUNPATH dynamic section attribute of the binary if present.
> 4. Lookup based on the ldconfig cache file (often located at /etc/ld.so.cache) which contains a compiled list of candidate
>      libraries previously found in the augmented library path (set by
>      /etc/ld.so.conf). If, however, the binary was linked with the -z
>      nodeflib linker option, libraries in the default library paths are
>      skipped.
> 5. In the trusted default path /lib, and then /usr/lib. If the binary was linked with the -z nodeflib linker option, this step is
>      skipped.

To see if a binary has an RPATH configured:

> readelf -d filename      Shows only data from the “dynamic” section
>
> The “dynamic” section of the header is of interest because it contains
>   data used during the initial loading process, such as:
>
> ```
> NEEDED: libraries needed by this module
> RPATH: See “Loader search procedure” below
> SONAME: If this module is a library, this item shows the “soname” of the library.
> ```

Source: [The linux loader, and how it finds libraries: ld-linux and so on](https://grahamwideman.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/the-linux-loader-and-how-it-finds-libraries/)

To view all libraries in the ldconfig cache you can run

```
ldconfig -p
```

An example of RUNPATH set in a binary

```
$ readelf -d /opt/teamviewer9/tv_bin/TVGuiSlave.64 | grep -i RUNPATH
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [${ORIGIN}/../lib]
```

Answer (score 1):

The system will search first within `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and then in the paths specified in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.