# How to determine where an executable searches for a shared library?

Tags: dynamic-linking

I know I have the library, but the executable can't find it. If I knew where it was searching, I could just create a symlink where it expects to find the lib.

```
$ ~/Apps/simutrans/simutrans
/home/dan/Apps/simutrans/simutrans: error while loading shared libraries: libbz2.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ locate libbz2
...
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so
...
```

Apparently, the executable isn't using `/etc/ld.so.conf*` to find libraries; if it was, then it would have found the lib:

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf 
# Multiarch support
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Inspecting the executable with `readelf`, as mentioned in [where will the system search for dynamic libraries?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171632/where-will-the-system-search-for-dynamic-libraries), doesn't show a `RUNPATH` entry that would have shown when the library needs to be found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your program runs with the current user (no setuid, etc), you can use [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to get this information, e.g.,

```
strace -o foo.out ~/Apps/simutrans/simutrans
```

and look in the output file for `open` calls.

Comment: Found it, created a symlink, and now the executable crashes with `/home/dan/Apps/simutrans/simutrans: error while loading shared libraries: libbz2.so.1.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`. Looks like I got handed a 32 bit version.